# Why does a variable that gets assigned inside a Proc not persist over repeated calls of the Proc?

Tags: ruby, block, scope

Ruby 1.9.2 code:

```
def append_string_to_text(string_to_append)
  string_to_alter = 'starting_bit'
  p "OUTSIDE BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is #{string_to_alter.object_id}"
  Proc.new do
    p "****** START OF BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is #{string_to_alter.object_id}"
    p "defined?(new_string_created_in_block) is #{defined?(new_string_created_in_block) == true}"
    unless defined?(new_string_created_in_block)
      p "new_string_created_in_block is undefined. lets define it."
      new_string_created_in_block = 'test'
    end
    p "new_string_created_in_block.object_id is #{new_string_created_in_block.object_id}"
    string_to_alter = string_to_alter + string_to_append
    p "END OF BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is #{string_to_alter.object_id}"
    string_to_alter
  end
end

proc = append_string_to_text('_text_at_the_end')
p proc.call
p proc.call
```

Output:

```
"OUTSIDE BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is 70283335840820"
"****** START OF BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is 70283335840820"
"defined?(new_string_created_in_block) is false"
"new_string_created_in_block is undefined. lets define it."
"new_string_created_in_block.object_id is 70283335840520"
"END OF BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is 70283335840440"
"starting_bit_text_at_the_end"
"****** START OF BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is 70283335840440"
"defined?(new_string_created_in_block) is false"
"new_string_created_in_block is undefined. lets define it."
"new_string_created_in_block.object_id is 70283335840180"
"END OF BLOCK: string_to_alter.object_id is 70283335840100"
"starting_bit_text_at_the_end_text_at_the_end"
```

The first time the block is run, the `string_to_alter` variable initially points to the object created at the start of the `append_string_to_text` method, because the block is a closure. The block creates a new variable `new_string_created_in_block`, and then creates a new block local variable `string_to_alter`, which is shadowing the outer variable `string_to_alter`.

The second time the block is run, the `string_to_alter` variable initially points to the object created during the first time the block was run.

Why is it that during this second run, `new_string_created_in_block` is undefined? It gets assigned during the first run, and the assigning of the `string_to_alter` variable gets persisted from the first run, so why doesn't `new_string_created_in_block` persist as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string_to_alter` gets persisted because it's outside of the `Proc` block and part of the closure. The `Proc` block itself gets instantiated at each invocation, however, hence the lack of persistence of any  of the variables defined within the block.